# C++ Help for pointer especially "->" operator

Tags: c++, pointers

Hi guys I have a problem with "->" operator . Here is my code :
and `OfferingPair * weeklySchedule ;` decleared inside of `Schedule` class and   OfferingPair is decleared inside a header file.

```
struct     OfferingPair
{
  Offering     * off     ;
  OfferingPair * nextOff ;

}


Schedule::Schedule ()
{
    this->weeklySchedule=new OfferingPair[5];

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        weeklySchedule[i]->off=NULL;
        weeklySchedule[i]->nextOff=NULL;
    }   
}
```

and  because of the :

```
weeklySchedule[i]->off=NULL;
weeklySchedule[i]->nextOff=NULL;
```

lines i got an error which says :

```
base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘OfferingPair’
```

but weeklySchedule[i] is a pointer why i can not use "->" ?.Thanks in advance.

Comment: "`weeklySchedule[i]` is a pointer" - the compiler doesn't agree with you. So show the code: how is `weeklySchedule` declared?

Comment: @PeteBecker since it's assigned to `new OfferingPair[5];`, I'm betting it's declared as `OfferingPair*`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - maybe. But analyzing type errors starts with actual declarations, not guesses and not bets. <g>

Comment: I need  more explanation ,i still have questions..

Comment: @user1757052:  What are those questions?

Comment: I want to assign a offeringpair pointer for each day from monday to friday thats why i implement the this->weeklySchedule=new OfferingPair[5]; line.After that line i guessed i can reach the day monday with weeklyScheule[0] but everyone says that it's wrong, but nobody says how could i do it ?

Answer (score 14):

`weeklySchedule[i]` returns the object itself, not a pointer, so you have to use `.`

```
weeklySchedule[i].off=NULL;
weeklySchedule[i].nextOff=NULL;
```

I suggest you modify your code to:

```
std::vector<OfferingPair> weeklySchedule
```

though. It's the RAIIght (c) thing to do.

Comment: What do you mean with "returns the object itself ? ".weeklySchedule[i] points to struct which contains off and nextOff pointers.

Comment: @user1757052 no, `weeklySchedule[i]` **is** a struct which contains off and nextOff pointers...

Comment: @user1757052 weeklySchedule is `[OfferingPair, OfferingPair, ..]` NOT `[OfferingPair*, OfferingPair*, ..]`

Comment: @user1757052, please mark the answer which is the best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Others already pointed out the problem of `->` vs. dot (`.`) syntax.

But I'd like to elaborate a bit on other sides.

Since you are initializing your `OfferingPair::off` and `nextOff` data members to `NULL`, maybe this work should be done inside `OfferingPair` *default constructor*:

```
struct OfferingPair
{
  ....

  OfferingPair()
    : off(NULL)
    , nextOff(NULL)
  {
  }
};
```

And you can just use a `std::vector` instead of a raw C-like array to store instances of the above structure.
Add a data member to your `Schedule` class like this:

```
  std::vector<OfferingPair> m_weeklySchedule;
```

And then in the default constructor create a `std::vector` of 5 items:

```
Schedule::Schedule()
  : m_weeklySchedule(5)
{
}
```

Note how your code is *simplified*.

Note also that you don't need an explicit `delete[]` in your destructor to release the array dynamically allocated memory: `std::vector`'s destructor will be *automatically* called and will take care of that.

Moreover, the compiler generated copy constructor and copy `operator=` will do the right thing with *member-wise copy* (calling the corresponding `std::vector` copy operations), instead with a raw C-like array you have to write proper code for copy constructor and `operator=` (or ban them, declaring them `private`).

**EDIT:**
You seem to have edited your original post adding new code, in particular some sketch of the `OfferingPair` data structure:

```
struct OfferingPair
{
  Offering     * off;
  OfferingPair * nextOff;
};
```

The fact that you have a *pointer to the next* `OfferingPair` inside `OfferingPair` makes me think that maybe you just need a linked list of `Offering`'s? Unless this is a learning exercise for linked lists, maybe you just need a `std::list<Offering>`, or a C++11 `std::forward_list<Offering>`?

Answer (score 0):

The array index operator is basically defined as follows:

`a[b]` = `*(a + (b))`

The `->` operator is basically defined as follows:

`a->b` = `(*a).b`

So when you write:

```
weeklySchedule[i]->off=NULL;
```

You are writing this:

```
(*(*(weeklySchedule + i))).off=NULL;
```

Notice how you are dereferencing the pointer twice. Clearly this is incorrect!